# Having a hard time updating an array of objects in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
this.state = {
  currentClient: 1,
  currentInvoice: null,

  clientsList: [
    {
      clientID: 2,
      InvoiceNumber: null,
    },
    {
      clientID: null,
      InvoiceNumber: null,
    },
  ],
};
```

I tried this, however it does not work, my values stays always null.

```
this.setState({[clientsList[currentClient]]}: {this.state.currentClient, this.state.currentInvoice})
```

then I tried this with the spread operator

```
client= {this.state.currentClient: this.state.currentInvoice}

this.setState(prevState => ({
    clientsList: {                   
        ...prevState.clientsList,    
        name: client       
    }
}))
```

this did not really work and I always ended up with only one client on the array.

also each clientID need to correspond to it position on the array

Comment: Can you give us an example of a before and after of your expected array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the spread operator, you could do something like this, but I'm not sure what your `currentClient` object looks like since it's null in your example.

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState, //copy current state
    clientsList: [
        //copy current clients list with currentClient object filtered out            
        ...prevState.clientsList.filter( e => e.clientID !== this.state.currentClient.clientID),
        { //replace client object
            clientID: this.state.currentClient
            InvoiceNumber: this.state.currentInvoice
        }
    ]
}))
```

Comment: it's just numbers

Comment: your last piece of code worked for me. thank you. everything works great. disregard what I wrote about duplicate. thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be so many syntax error in your snippets, can't understand what you need to acomplish.
If you want to update a name on the clientList array you might need to transform the previous list with a map and set it back to the state.

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
    clientsList: prevState.clientsList.map( it => ({
        ...it, 
        ...(client === it.clientId && {name: client})
     }))                        
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry unable to understand your code here, why have you used `this.setState({[clientsList[currentClient]]}: {this.state.currentClient, this.state.currentInvoice})` the state is of not this type right? I believe there is some misunderstanding about how arrays are used.

I am just guessing but if you want is to update the array with your current selection then I would have used the following initial state

```
this.state = {
  clientsList: [];
}
```

And when the values for `clientsList` is available you can update it using (assuming you get `clientsList` in another variable called `newClientsList`)

```
this.setState({clientsList: [...newClientsList]});
```

And if you want to update a client detail and know which index of array you want to update you can simply do the following (again assuming the updated clientId and updated invoice number are coming from variables `updatedClientId` and `updatedInvoiceNumber`)

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const clients = [...prevState.clientsList];
  clients[clientIndex] = {clientId: updatedClientId, invoiceNumber: updatedInoviceNumber};
  return {clientsList: clients}
});
```

And if you wan to add a new client at the end of the array then you can use the following code (again assuming you get that info from newClientId and newInvoiceNumber)

```
this.setState({clientsList: clientsList.concat({clientId: newClientId, invoiceNumber: newInvoiceNumber});
```